# Consider set $C^{1}[0,1]$ with defined norm as above.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Consider set $C^{1}[0,1]$ with define the norm $||f||_{D}$= $\left(
>  \int_0^1(f(x)^{2}dx \right)^{1/2} +
>  \left(\int_0^{1}(f^{'}(x))^{2}dx\right)^{1/2}  $ Check that it's
>   Banach space.

CounterExample:

Consider $$f_{n}(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sin(nx)$$ uniformly convergence to zero, 
but the derivative is  $$f^{'}(x) = cos(nx)$$ not uniformly on $[0,1]$

Please check my intuition. Many thanks!

Edit:

I have some issue with this example for integrate of $\int_0^{1}(f'(x))^{2}$ = $\frac{1}{2}(nx + \sin(nx)\cos(nx))$ it's uniformly convergent to 0.

Comment: I don't get your "counterexample". $\|f\|_D = \|f\|_2+\|f'\|_2$ is a norm on $C^1$. If we have a Cauchy sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ with respect to such a norm then $\lim_{n\to +\infty} f_n(x)$ exists as a $C^1$ function.

Comment: Yes, I am bit confusing, exists as $C^1$ function why?

Comment: If $\|g_n\|_D\to 0$ then both $\|g_n\|_2$ and $\|g_n'\|_2$ converge to zero. If $\{f_n'\}$ is a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions, its limit is a continuous function.